# Forward and backward pass in Conv2D transpose Layer

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, convolution, backpropagation

I’ve several questions regarding the transposed convolution 2d layer. I’ve not been able to find a proper resource explaining the forward and backward pass. What I know (but not for sure) is, that this layer can be emulated by adding stride - 1 zeros between the input pixels and kernel_size - 1 zeros to the input’s border. Doing so, causes the deltas for the original input (before fancy padding) do not match.

Could someone tell me in details how to handle this or a different approach to implement forward and backward pass for this layer type.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean *the deltas for the original input do not match*?

Comment: Consider an input of size k, this input is than manipulated by adding zeros of kernel_size-1 to the border and stride-1 zeros in between. The upper layers output, the input to the manipulating layer, is expecting deltas of size k. Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: Not exactly. The way I think of it is that each weight has a specific role. It multiplies its inputs and then feeds them to an activation function (regardless if those inputs are normal ones or zero-padding). This is then concatenated with some more padding and given as the input of the next layer etc. I don't see why you can't compute the derivative for this weight, given that you know the path that its output takes to generate the loss. Maybe I'm thinking of it wrong...

Comment: I’ve added a photo so you might be able to understand it better. The gradients for the weights are not a problem but the gradients for the output of the previous layer.